# Inspecting method body in Chrome debugger

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, console, contextmenu

So before yesterday I always had an option of inspecting the method body in Chrome debugger by simply hovering it's name. But now that functionality works only for properties and not methods for some reason. And also when I type the method name in console it doesn't output it's body like it used to do. So i have to manually locate that method in source code to view it.

Is it something that can be manually turned on/off or it's just the way it will be from now on?